# How to do async on Google App Engine?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, android-asynctask

What are all the ways to run asynchronous threads on Google App Engine (for Java)? I can think of one - but I want to know all of them/

Comment: Asynchronous what?  Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no way to start an asynchronous thread directly, but each request will have its own thread and you can make many, many asynchronous requests!

There are at least four ways to make requests:

- With the UrlFetch api
- With task queues
- With cron
- With requests from clients or other servers
- With [Background Threads](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview#background_threads) started in Backends

Comment: How about put your work in a finalizer and let the finalizer thread run it. https://twitter.com/#!/headius/status/43774794688237568

Comment: Ok, so the finalize method will run in a different thread from your initial request, but only after relevant objects are unreachable by other code. I recommend that you not consider the garbage collector as a way to achieve multithreading.

Comment: @NickJohnson I can't be expected to remember how to spell "Queues" *and* perfectly remember the name of _every number!_

Comment: There are also async calls to the datastore https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/async